# Need to limit the torque on a spooler

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller, current-limiting, torque

I'm a newbie to DC motors. I'm trying to use a geared DC motor of 150RPM 70Ncm torque to pull in rope on a small spool. The rope is being released by other equipment. This rope is being released at different ratesbl (+/- 50% variation) from the equipment. I would like to immediately gobble up this rope whenever released else it'll snag with another rope.

The tricky bit is I need to make the DC motor not pull too much on the rope when no rope is being released by the equipment but immediately gobble up the rope whenever released.

Can I achieve this using a high RPM motor and use something like a torque limiter?

If yes how?

If not what are the possible solutions?

Comment: You could also do this mechanically with whatever the thing they use in a torque wrench is called.

Comment: @Hearth Which kind? I assume you mean the click and release kind and not the beam kind which just gives you a readout on a dial. I guess a friction clutch would work too.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yeah, that's the kind I meant, the kind that "break" (not actually break, just release a clutch or something) when you exceed the set torque. I didn't know there were ones that just gave you a readout, though it makes sense that they'd exist--I've always just seen a socket adapter with a torque meter on it used for that.

Comment: Be careful with the current limit. When the motor is in stall, only a part of the inner windings take all the current and heat spreading is worse for the motor.

Answer (score 4):

The trick here is usually to use a constant current power supply. Broadly speaking, DC motors behave as follows:

- Constant voltage tends to give a reasonably constant speed with varying loads.
- Constant current tends to give a reasonably constant torque at varying loads.

If you have access to a suitable lab power supply you can test this out quite easily by setting the current limit.

You need to watch the power dissipation in the motor. You should set your current at somewhat less than \$ I_{max} = \frac P V \$ where ***P*** is the rated power of the motor in watts and ***V*** is the rated voltage.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running this on a portable unit using a battery, how do I provide constant current? Is there a circuit/module I can use?

Comment: There will be many possible solutions. We don't recommend products on this site so I recommend that you do some experimental measurements and draw up a specification for your requirements. This would include input voltage (battery), maximum current required, the adjustment range (if required) and the maximum voltage required to maintain that current / torque at maximum speed. Only then can you start looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

One method to monitor the tension is to have the rope riding over an idler pulley that is spring tensioned. Much like that little thing on the gear changer on a rear wheel of a bicycle. You can measure the displacement of the pulley and if it goes too far in either direction the tension is either too high or too low.

Answer (score 2):

Using a torque motor (they are designed to be stalled), or adding a "dancer" (a preloaded idler with a sensor) and a closed-loop controller are two ways this is typically approached.

A really simple approach that might work in your case is to add a series power resistor to the DC motor that will limit the stall current to no more than normal full-load operating current (a bit less since some cooling may occur from internal motion eg. a fan or just the armature spinning). Say the motor is 2A full-load  at 24V you could add about a 15 ohm resistor in series, rated at 50 or  75W. If less that full-load torque is required, you can use a higher value resistor, but it has to overcome friction in the gear train etc.